# Sqlalchemy ORM query fails if actual column name is in lower case

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a simple **python3** script which queries *Employee* table using **Sqlalchemy orm(1.3)** and the underlying database is **Sqlite3**. This script works fine if *Employee* table has column with name "**Id**" but it fails if the column name is "**id**"(lowercase). Is there a way to make this script work whether the column name is "**Id**" or "**id**". Basically I want to make this script work irrespective of column names case sensitivity.

Here is the code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm.query import Query
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
import sys


engine = create_engine(sys.argv[1])
metadata = MetaData(engine)
base = automap_base()
base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
employee_table = base.classes["Employee"]
query = Query(employee_table).filter(employee_table.Id.in_(['100', '200']))
```

and I run this from command line as `python3 test.py sqlite:///temp.db`

and this is the error I am receiving:

> AttributeError: type object 'Employee' has no attribute 'Id'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a generic solution, please see [Intercepting Column Definitions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/automap.html#intercepting-column-definitions) documentation page.

*Less elegant, but `if` statement would also work:*

```
if hasattr(employee_table, 'Id'):
   id_attr = getattr(employee_table, 'Id')
elif hasattr(employee_table, 'id'):
   id_attr = getattr(employee_table, 'id')
else:
   raise ...

query = Query(employee_table).filter(id_attr.in_(['100', '200']))
```

Answer (score 1):

sqlite table & column names are case-insensitive, so that's why you're running into this problem. It's not a sqlalchemy issue, but rather a sqlite issue.